# Parsing local xml file with iOS swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I was looking at this example for parsing xml using swift
http://ashishkakkad.com/2014/10/xml-parsing-in-swift-language-ios-8-nsxmlparser/

as you can see in the example, the xml file is located somewhere in the web

```
var url:String="http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml"
var urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)
```

I want to do the same, but instead I want to have the xml file locally as part of my single view project. 
Where in the project I should place the xml file?

How can I access it from the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drag the file anywhere in your XCode project. Then you just access it like

```
let xmlPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "xml")
let xmlData = NSData(contentsOfFile: xmlPath)
```

Now you can parse your xmlData.I use AEXML for that purpose, but you can use any other libraries.

Comment: @borna glad you're getting with it, mark as answer please!

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code

`let xmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testfile", ofType: "xml")
 let xmlData = NSData(contentsOfFile: xmlPath!)`

Comment: Better use Bundle.main.url than Bundle.main.path and better use Data than NSData.